# How to assign several users to a meeting

Tags: sugarcrm

**What I want to do:**
I would like to add several users (employees) for a meeting. I won't build a team, because there is no need : there are two commercials : the boss (who is a commercial) and the other commercial. Not much to build a team.
Effectively, I can assign only one user, and change him, but not add another employee to the meeting.

**What I've tried:**
I tried to change the relationships of the field "meetings_assigned_users" , but obviously this is in gray shade and i can't modify it.

**So:**
How could I add a "plus" button in the detail-edit-create views to assign another user?
Do I have to build another field/module by myself?

Thanks to air4x, I achieved it by adding "invitees" to the meetings! (I thought the Invitees button added just contacts, not employees.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While editing a meeting you can find a panel titled 'Add Invitees' at the bottom of the page. Fill Email text box with the email address of another user and click search. Now the other user will be fetched and displayed below. Click the add button to include this user in the Meeting.